# Error while retrieveing BLOB field from database?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, crystal-reports, blob

I'm trying to retrieve a BLOB field from Oracle and show it in a crystal report.
While viewing the report, I've that error:

```
Failed to open a rowset.
Details: ADO Error Code: 0x
Source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for oracle
Description: Unspecified error
```

I use a View as report datasource, its script

```
SELECT COMPANY_ID, COMPANY_LOGO FROM ID_COMPANY_SETUP;
```

I'm using CrystalReport embedded with VS.NET 2005.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what type of rowset are you opening?

Comment: I don't actually, what type of rowset as report itself is responsible for retrieving data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got where was the problem. It was "Connection Type".

I were using OLE DB(ADO) for connection to database, while I changed it to 
Oracle Server connection, blob field retrieved properly.